# How does Google Chrome know my Firefox history if I never imported it?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, privacy, history

I have Firefox and Google Chrome installed in the same machine (Linux). It happens when I type something in Chrome Omnibox it suggests pages I have already visited in Firefox.

- I have never connected the accounts of both browsers
- I have never imported information from one browser to other
- I have never visited the suggested pages in Chrome
- The keyword I type in the omnibox is vague and there is no way it could guess the suggestion without having access to the Firefox history. i.e.: i type "ir" in Chrome and it suggests me the same Iron Maiden lyrics page I have browse before in Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any synchronization extensions like Xmarks installed?

Comment: No, I dont. It is a clean installation.

Comment: Could it be that you're logged into Google, which remembers your previous searches an auto-suggests them?

Comment: I have logged into Google only in Google Chrome.

Comment: What happens if you reset your profile (e.g. move/rename `~/.config/google-chrome`)?

Comment: I did that and Chrome does not show those suggestions again. Another thing I have noticed is that those items are not listed in Chrome history and not all items in the Firefox history are known to Chrome.

Comment: @slhck: The suggested pages were not searched in Google, I have access them directly from the bookmarks in Firefox.

Comment: @fdisk Is the history actually showing up in your chrome://history/? Or is the omnibox simply just guessing your searches pretty accurately?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the Chrome installer ever asking for permission to pull your history.

Since the firefox history is in a set location, it is not hard for Chrome to pull it without your express permission.